# Insert &pound; before number

Tags: php, regex

This whole problem has come up because our data input people are useless. We have a form for adding items to a database, and one of the fields is a price. The format is something like `lowest - highest (lowest without 10% fee - highest without 10% fee)`, e.g. `11 - 22 (10 - 20)`

The problem is the people adding this data are REALLY inconsistent with adding the pound sign, so some are like `11-£22(£10-20)`, so my idea is when I'm bringing back the data, remove any £ sign in there, and re add them all, so they will all look the same.

I'm guessing to do this I will need some sort of RegEx to match something, but I'm not sure what the pattern would be.

Can anyone help me figure out what RegEx I'd need to use?

Comment: If *you* are the programmer then I would be careful with statements like "data input people are useless"... ;-P What specific regex flavour are we talking about here?

Comment: Oops, forgot to say, it's PHP

Comment: Help the people being less useless and provide an input mask in the form.

Comment: If you expect there to be pounds in the database's column, is there much point in storing the £? Why not just have a float/decimal column and render the string with a pound sign?

Comment: If you're letting non-technical users input data, inconsistent data is **your** fault, not theirs. They don't know any better, but you should know full well that monetary data should be stored as numbers, not strings, and that validation of proper input format is critical.

Comment: -1: You didn't say, what output do you want to get. In the title, you said, that you want to insert a pound symbol before number. In the text, you said, that you want to "remove any £ sign in there". Show us samples of input data and the desired result.

Comment: Not sure why you need a regular expression for this; if you're expecting it not to have any £ symbols in it, just remove all of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your regex flavour supports lookarounds you could use the expression:

```
£?(?<!\d)(\d+)
```

and use the following as the replacement:

```
£\1
```

This should work fine in PHP

You could also use this expression if you expect the price to contain commas and full-stops

```
£?(?<![0-9,.])(\d+)
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution would be to provide a drop down with  a list of currency symbols.  That way the addition of the symbol is obvious to the users.

You can still add an expression, could replace all non-numeric characters and allow a single `dot` character and many `commas`.

You could also user javascript to restrict the entered characters, but provide server side validation/modification anyway.

Comment: That's no good for data input, it slows down the operation too much.

Comment: @vascowhite The OP specifies a single currency, so it could probably default to the pound.

Comment: Its a balancing act between operational performance (user experience) and data integrity.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this:

```
$result = preg_replace('~£?(\d+)~', '£$1', '11-£22(£10-20)');
```